# Numpy: is this the fastest way to slice+'leftover' a mulltidim array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume I have a multidimensional Numpy Array. Now I want to:

- *Slice out a certain row range* defined by `startIndex` and `endIndex`.
- Get a array with the *original array minus the slice* (so the left over).

The code below does this trick, however is this the most performance one?

- Because my array is very big, can I **(memory neutral) slice out the original array so that afterwards the original array is the left over. So except some overhead for the header of the new array this will cost no additional memory?**
- Is my snippet below (with creating new arrays), **the the most efficient solution if we retain the original array?**

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.random((6, 2))
print('Orig',X)
startIndex = 2
endIndex = 4
print('Slice ',X[startIndex:endIndex])
print('LeftOver ',np.concatenate((X[:startIndex-1],X[endIndex:])))
```

**Output:**

```
Orig [[ 0.94661646  0.3911347 ]
 [ 0.6807441   0.676658  ]
 [ 0.81109554  0.18089991]
 [ 0.6161699   0.19907537]
 [ 0.12859196  0.34866049]
 [ 0.22283545  0.04949782]]
Slice  [[ 0.81109554  0.18089991]
 [ 0.6161699   0.19907537]]
LeftOver  [[ 0.94661646  0.3911347 ]
 [ 0.12859196  0.34866049]
 [ 0.22283545  0.04949782]]
```

Comment: This is a good way of constructing `leftover`, but it does construct a new array with its own data. All slices are views, but concatenate copies. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate make a copy, and you need it if order matters.

But if your slices are slim, and order doesn't matter, a more economic way can be:

```
import numpy as np
size=6
X = np.random.random((size, 2))
print('Orig\n',X)
startIndex = 3
endIndex = 5
Slice=X[startIndex:endIndex].copy()
length = min(endIndex-startIndex,size-endIndex) # to check overlap
X[startIndex:startIndex+length]=X[-length:]
Left=X[:size-len(Slice)]
print('Slice\n',Slice)
print('LeftOver\n',Left)
```

because at most  2x the size of the slice is copied, not the whole array.

it gives:

```
Orig
 [[ 0.39351322  0.42100711]
 [ 0.14793363  0.12149344]
 [ 0.94524844  0.22004186]
 [ 0.816418    0.35630767]
 [ 0.37781821  0.12336287]
 [ 0.65995888  0.23812275]]
Slice
 [[ 0.816418    0.35630767]
 [ 0.37781821  0.12336287]]
LeftOver
 [[ 0.39351322  0.42100711]
 [ 0.14793363  0.12149344]
 [ 0.94524844  0.22004186]
 [ 0.65995888  0.23812275]]
```

Comment: Ugly, but effective when `size` gets in the 10000 range (based on some quick timings).